# generic form validation based on the input name or id

Tags: jquery, validation

I don't know whether this is the proper place to ask this question.
if not please migrate to the appropriate stackexchange forum.

I want to extend jQuery.validate to validate the fields regardless of the form.
By saying this i mean:

If i have to validate an email fields i will write the rule only once in a separate script page and include it globally. But i want the plugin to pick up the same rule where ever i have email fields.

eg: `<input type="text" name="email" id="email" data-set="required,email" data-mesg="required mesg, email mesg" />`

If somebody can suggest some links for starting it, would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

See the jQuery Validation docs: http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element

You can set up your rules for the form, since jQuery validation only validates forms, then validate individual elements when you need to:

Example from the docs:

```
var validator = $( "form" ).validate({/*your rules*/});
validator.element( "#email" );
```